# Is there any similar property like NestedScrollingEnabled of Android.Widget.ScrollView available in UIKit.UIScrollView?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.ios

I am working for custom scheduler control in Xamarin.Forms which has native renderers in each platform. Scheduler working fine, but if we place Schedler inside a ScrollView then scrolling not working for parent scrollview.

In Android renderer, I used NestedScrollingEnabled property now everything working in android but can't find similar functionality in Xamarin.iOS and UWP platforms.

I am using below native scroll views.

Xamarin.iOS - UIKit.UIScrollView

UWP - Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ScrollViewer

Please help me to achieve the behavior.

Comment: What is the Schedler  in your case ? Another ScrollView or a ListView ?

Comment: It is ScrollView

Comment: There are no conflictive scrolling between to ScrollViews . So you could share your sample so that I can test it on my side .